# Delete node based on other node's attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, xml-dml

I have the following XML being returned in SQL and I would like to use SQL XML DML to conditionally remove a node based on the value of a different node.  In my example, I would like to remove the “Color” node when the value of the “Value” attribute of the “Size” node is equal to “S”.

```
<root>
            <ParentGroup>
                            <ChildGroup Id="1">
                                            <Child Id="1">
                                                            <Color Value="Red"/>
                                                            <Size Value="L"/>
                                            </Child>
                                            <Child Id="2">
                                                            <Color Value="Blue"/>
                                                            <Size Value="S"/>
                                            </Child>
                            </ChildGroup>
                            <ChildGroup Id="2">
                                            <Child Id="5">
                                                            <Color Value="Blue"/>
                                                            <Size Value="L"/>
                                            </Child>
                                            <Child Id="9">
                                                            <Color Value="Red"/>
                                                            <Size Value="S"/>
                                            </Child>
                            </ChildGroup>
            </ParentGroup>
</root>
```

I would like the resulting XML to be:

```
<root>
            <ParentGroup>
                            <ChildGroup Id="1">
                                            <Child Id="1">
                                                            <Color Value="Red"/>
                                                            <Size Value="L"/>
                                            </Child>
                                            <Child Id="2">
                                                            <Size Value="S"/>
                                            </Child>
                            </ChildGroup>
                            <ChildGroup Id="2">
                                            <Child Id="5">
                                                            <Color Value="Blue"/>
                                                            <Size Value="L"/>
                                            </Child>
                                            <Child Id="9">
                                                            <Size Value="S"/>
                                            </Child>
                            </ChildGroup>
            </ParentGroup>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `predicate` to reduce the `<Child>`-nodes to a list, which fullfills your condition:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
  <ParentGroup>
    <ChildGroup Id="1">
      <Child Id="1">
        <Color Value="Red" />
        <Size Value="L" />
      </Child>
      <Child Id="2">
        <Color Value="Blue" />
        <Size Value="S" />
      </Child>
    </ChildGroup>
    <ChildGroup Id="2">
      <Child Id="5">
        <Color Value="Blue" />
        <Size Value="L" />
      </Child>
      <Child Id="9">
        <Color Value="Red" />
        <Size Value="S" />
      </Child>
    </ChildGroup>
  </ParentGroup>
</root>';
```

--The query will search for a `<Child>` where the attribute `Value` within `<Size>` is "S" and remove their `<Color>`

```
SET @xml.modify('delete /root/ParentGroup/ChildGroup/Child[Size/@Value="S"]/Color');

SELECT @xml;
```

if you need to introduce the "S" as a variable you can use `sql:variable()`

```
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(10)='S';
SET @xml.modify('delete /root/ParentGroup/ChildGroup/Child[Size/@Value=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]/Color');
```